# Rock, paper, scissors game Java applet

Tags: java, applet, awt

I'm having problems with my java applet. I've made a Rock paper scissors game and i have 2 problems which I can't solve:
1. how to load the applet without the rock image on the left (players choice)
2. the score for player and computer does not reduce by 1 for every lost game

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class RockScissorsPaper extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
private Button rockButton;
private Button scissorsButton;
private Button paperButton;
private String buttonPressed = "";
private int computerValue = -1;
private int myValue;
private int playerScore = 10;
private int computerScore = 10;
private int drawScore = 0;
private Image imgRock;
private Image imgScissors;
private Image imgPaper;

public void init()
{
    rockButton = new Button("Rock");
    scissorsButton = new Button("Scissors");
    paperButton = new Button("Paper");
    add(rockButton);
    add(scissorsButton);
    add(paperButton);
    rockButton.addActionListener(this);
    scissorsButton.addActionListener(this);
    paperButton.addActionListener(this);
    imgRock = getImage(getCodeBase(), "rock.jpg");
    imgScissors = getImage(getCodeBase(), "scissors.jpg");
    imgPaper = getImage(getCodeBase(), "paper.jpg");
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    buttonPressed = ((Button)event.getSource()).getLabel();
    computerValue = randomNumber012();
    translator(buttonPressed);
    repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    rockButton.setLocation(20,260);
    rockButton.setSize(70,35);
    paperButton.setLocation(210, 260);
    paperButton.setSize(70, 35);
    scissorsButton.setLocation(380, 260);
    scissorsButton.setSize(90, 35);
    choice(g);
    g.drawString("Player's Wins: " + playerScore, 10, 20);
    g.drawString("Computer's Wins: " + computerScore, 180, 20);
    g.drawString("Draws: " + drawScore, 400, 20);
    g.drawString("Your Choice: " + buttonPressed, 20, 60);
    g.drawString("Computer's Pick: ", 350, 60);
    winner(g, computerValue, myValue);
}

int randomNumber012()
{
    return (int)(Math.random()*3);
}

public void translator(String s)
{
    if(s.equals("Rock"))
    {
        myValue = 0;
    }
    else if(s.equals("Scissors"))
    {
        myValue = 1;
    }
    else if(s.equals("Paper"))
    {
        myValue = 2;
    }
}

public void choice(Graphics g)
{
    if(myValue == 0)
    {
        g.drawImage(imgRock, 20, 100, 100, 60, this);
    }
    else if(myValue == 1)
    {
        g.drawImage(imgScissors, 20, 100, 100, 60, this);
    }
    else if(myValue == 2)
    {
        g.drawImage(imgPaper, 20, 100, 100, 60, this);
    }

    if(computerValue == 0)
    {
        g.drawString("Computer's Pick: Rock", 350, 60);
        g.drawImage(imgRock, 350, 100, 100, 60, this);
    }
    else if(computerValue == 1)
    {
        g.drawString("Computer's Pick: Scissors", 350, 60);
        g.drawImage(imgScissors, 350, 100, 100, 60, this);
    }
    else if(computerValue == 2)
    {
        g.drawString("Computer's Pick: Paper", 350, 60);
        g.drawImage(imgPaper, 350, 100, 100, 60, this);
    }
}

public void winner(Graphics g, int cv, int mv)
{
    if(cv == -1)
    {
        g.drawString("", 200, 100);
    }
    else if(cv == mv)
    {
        g.drawString("Draw", 200, 250);
        drawScore = drawScore + 1;
    }
    else if(cv == 0 && mv == 1 || cv == 2 && mv == 0 || cv == 1 && mv == 2)
    {
        g.drawString("Computer Wins", 200, 250);
        playerScore = playerScore - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        g.drawString("You Win!", 200, 250);
        computerScore = computerScore - 1;
    }

    if (playerScore == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("You lost!");
        playerScore = 10;
        computerScore = 10;
        drawScore = 0;
    }
    else if(computerScore == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("You won!");
        playerScore = 10;
        computerScore = 10;
        drawScore = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged it yourself yet?  Are you actually ever getting to the line `playerScore = playerScore - 1;`?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 1):

> how to load the applet without the rock image on the left (players choice)

You need to have a fourth case for your `myValue` variable, when the player has not made a choice yet. Right now you only have three potential values, and the default is 0, which is why you see a rock image before you make a choice.

> the score for player and computer does not reduce by 1 for every lost game

You're using `int`s where you should be using `enum`s and `boolean`s, which is making your code harder to understand. I'd highly recommend refactoring your code to use `enum`s and `boolean`s instead of `int`s.

Also, you're always calling every method from the paint() method. Don't do that. Instead, only call the functions that check for a winner when the player actually makes a choice, presumably from a button click.

Finally, you're also calling `setLocation()` inside your `paint()` method, which is a bad idea. You should only call `setLocation()` once, or better yet, use a layout manager.